# С#. Хочу понять как в консольном приложении ограничить ввод данных пользователя до цифр

Tags: c#, консоль

Хочу понять как в консольном приложении ограничить ввод данных пользователя до цифр (чтоб вводились только цифры). Код нужен максимально простой и с максимальным разьяснением, очень хочу именно понять как все работает и как применяется, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Я нашёл следующий код, но не понимаю его:

```
public static string ReadDigitsFromConsole()
{
    string result = "";
    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                if (result.Length > 0)
                {
                    result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
                    Console.Write(key.KeyChar + " " + key.KeyChar);
                }
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                Console.WriteLine();
                return result;
            default:
                if (char.IsDigit(key.KeyChar))
                {
                    Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
                    result += key.KeyChar;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы подробные комментарии по поводу данного кода, что то не могу въехать :(

Comment: Ручной ввод без эхо, контроль, вывод эхо если надо. Читайте про Console.ReadKey(bool), ConsoleKeyInfo и Console.Write. С телефона более подробно писать не удобно, но на MSDN достаточно подробные примеры, чтобы разобраться самостоятельно

Comment: Я посмотрел примеры, даже нашел решение на одном из сайтов, но все равно многого не понял :( . Можно у вас все таки попросить комментарии ,а  код я сейчас скину.

Comment: Ок, если корректные фрагменты кода можно будет скопировать, я их прокомментирую, и возможно поправлю ошибки, насколько это будет в моих силах. Если время терпит, то скорее всего смогу нормально ответить в районе среды, когда из больницы выпустят

Comment: Спасибо, выздоравливайте :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну код в общем-то правильный.
Он крутится в цикле по нажатым клавишам до тех пор, пока не будет нажат Enter.

В начале итерации код ожидает ввода клавиши с клавиатуры, ведённая клавиша не отображается (`ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);`).

Затем введённый символ проверяется. Если это не Backspace и не Enter (это часть `default:` в `switch`'е), то проверяется, цифра это или нет (`char.IsDigit`). Если да, цифра выводится на экран, и добавляется к результирующей строке. Иначе просто введённый символ игнорируется.

Если введён Backspace (`case ConsoleKey.Backspace:`) и в накопленной строке есть символы (`result.Length > 0`), то из этой строки удаляется последний символ. Теперь его нужно затереть на экране, для этого выводится Backspace (это приводит к отходу курсора на символ назад), пробел (затирает последний видимый символ) и снова Backspace (отойдём снова назад, т. к. пробел продвинул нас вперёд)ю

Если введён Enter, возвращаем результат. Всё!

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, очень помогло, с меня печеньки :)

Comment: @user273078: Рад, что помогло!